# log4j 2 adding multiple colors to console appender

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, log4j2

Hi I just downloaded and configured log4j-2. I am stuck on applying color codes to the `SlowConsole` console appender. My console appender is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="SlowConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=black, DEBUG=green, TRACE=blue}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="File" fileName="C:\log\out.txt">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="org.abc.ea.web" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <!--Log4j for the WEB MODULE -->
            <appender-ref ref="SlowConsole"/>
        </logger>
        <logger name="org.abc.ea.ejb" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <!--Log4j for the EJB MODULE -->
            <appender-ref ref="SlowConsole"/>
        </logger>
        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have two questions,

1. I am new to log4j, is this the right way to write xml config file?
2. How can i add two color codes to each log level?

   for example: DEBUG=green -> will output light green font, But i need it to be `dim` and `bold`

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a patch for the docs! Help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I downloaded log4j2-core-sources.jar and traced the [source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/log4j2/trunk/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/AnsiEscape.java). You can write it as below;

```
<Console name="SlowConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout disableAnsi="false"  pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}"/>
</Console>
```

I think log4j2 [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) and its examples may need to be updated.

Comment: Found a manual https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html search for `highlight{pattern}{style}`

Comment: @HarmeetSingh yeah this answer is bit old now.

Comment: I had to also do disableAnsi="false"

Comment: Just to add to @KalpeshSoni answer. `disableAnsi="false"` goes into `<PatternLayout/>` next to `pattern=""`

Comment: added disableAnsi="false"

Comment: Worked fine, but not with SlowConsole. I have replaced it with Console

Comment: Good catch Rasika

Comment: It starts working properly once I added disableAnsi="false", thank you

Answer (score 50):

For a log4j2 colored output that looks very close to Spring Boot's default logback console output:

```
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} %style{${sys:PID}}{magenta} [%15.15t] %style{%-40.40C{1.}}{cyan} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>
    </Console>
```

[image: Console Screenshot]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted after applying custom log config!

Comment: I get _Unrecognized conversion specifier [wEx] starting at position 209 in conversion pattern._ anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Yes it's looks like original Logback Spring logger. Exactly what I looked for. But it doesn't work without disableAnsi="false" attribute in PatternLayout tag. Thank you!

Comment: @ycomp I've modified pattern and the issue that you've mentioned is also resolved... Try following pattern:

`<PatternLayout disableAnsi="false" pattern="%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} %style{}{magenta} [%M] %style{%40C}{cyan} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%xEx}" />`

Answer (score 8):

When using the eclipse console, its nice to see errors in red and
all other logs in black. You can do this using Filters:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleStdOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <Console name="ConsoleStdErr" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
        <ThresholdFilter level="ERROR" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleStdOut" />
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleStdErr" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 6):

Spring Boot style:

```xml
<Properties>
  <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
    %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=green, TRACE=green} %style{${sys:PID}}{magenta} --- [%15.15t] %style{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} : %m%n%ex
  </Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
  <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
  </Console>
</Appenders>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%clr{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{faint} %clr{%5p} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n%xwEx"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This worked in my Spring Boot application.

But I am not sure if it will work without Spring Boot.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is looking to achieve the same with log4j2.properties file. Works for log4j2 2.17.1 and above versions

```
status = warn

# Name of the configuration
name = ConsoleAndRollingLogFileAppenderConfigDemo

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.disableAnsi=false
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=green, TRACE=green} %style{%pid}{magenta} --- [%15.15t] %style{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} : %m%n%ex

# Log files location
property.basePath = src/main/resources

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}/app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=green, TRACE=green} %style{%pid}{magenta} --- [%15.15t] %style{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} : %m%n%ex
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 100MB
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 30
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Delete all files older than 30 days
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 60d

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = debug

# Configure root logger
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

Answer (score 1):

1 : yes it's ok! and you can add some other options. see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

2 : you can use a HTMLLayout for your file appender.

see http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_htmllayout.htm

Comment: Thanks @Homayoun! My second question is not yet been solved. I am using a consoleAppender. I want my logs to be viewed on netbeans, eclipse or any STD_OUT. So HTMLLayout wont work, isnt it?

Comment: it depends on your stdout viewer... for example eclipse stdout (output) has not any sense about bold for example.

Answer (score 1):

In log4j2 2.18.0 significant improvements were added in highlighting and generated ANSI code:

- 4 bit color support was added. Before 2.18.0 it was possible to use `WARN=bright blue` but generated ANSI code anyway used only 3 bit color palette and set font weight as `bold`. Now it is possible to use all 16 colors and besides to change font weight. For this purpose it is necessary to use `bright_` prefix. For example `WARN=bright_blue` or with font weight `WARN=bright_blue bold`. For details see [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3537)
- true color support was added. For example, `WARN=#00ff00`. At the same time it is possible to change both foreground and background color. For details see this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3538). For example:

  ```
  %highlight{%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable}{FATAL=white, ERROR=red, WARN=bg_#5792e6 fg_#eef26b bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=#3fe0a8, TRACE=blue}
  ```