# How to print logs in color using log4j2 highlight pattern?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

I am new for log4j2.I want to print logs in different colors for different levels.I am using eclipse ide for development java with log4j2 for application logging.
This is my log4j2.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
   <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=black, DEBUG=green, TRACE=blue}"/>
   </Console>
  </Appenders>
   <loggers>
  <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="all"/>
    <root level="all">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</Configuration>
```

when i am execute the log4j2 example I am getting below result in eclipse console.

```
[32m15:56:30.536 DEBUG com.syn.test.Test.main() @15 - this is debug message
[m[32m15:56:30.539 DEBUG com.syn.test.Test.main() @19 - this is debug messge 
[m
```

now my question is how to print logs in different colors for different levels in eclipse console.

Comment: this answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979699/log4j-2-adding-multiple-colors-to-console-appender

Comment: this answer also gives same result in eclipse ide console.

Answer (score 5):

The ANSI Console plugin from Eclipse market place does the job.
It works great and you can see the logs in colors both on Windows & Unix

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: In Eclipse: Help -> Eclipse marketplace -> Find: Ansi, then install it

Answer (score 3):

The highlight and color syntax works on most `Unix` and `Mac` terminals but apparently not in the `Windows DOS` console (according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)).

Unfortunately, I very much doubt that the `Eclipse` console supports highlighting and colors with `ANSI` escape codes.

UPDATE:
`Windows` color support is possible with [`Jansi`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi).

Comment: means we can't print the logs in color in eclipse console and windows DOS console.there is any way to print the logs using log4j2.

Comment: You can print the logs, you just won't see colors or highlighting.

Comment: both features are available in log4j2.x i need both.

Comment: I updated my answer: you can get colors in the Windows console with Jansi.

Comment: Jansi URL is not at all open in my system.It's showing this page is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I had success in [`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea) using [`jcabi-log`](https://log.jcabi.com).

`Maven` dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcabi-log</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Example `PatternLayout`:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue}] [%t]: %logger{36}.%M@L%L - %msg%n" disableAnsi="false"/>
```

It's important to retain the `disableAnsi="false"` property to make the colors work.