# How to print logs in color using log4php?

Tags: php, logging

I am new for log4php. I want to print logs in different colors for different levels.

In log4j2 manual, I found `highlight{pattern}{style}` (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html)

But for log4php,I found nothing. 
Is it possible with log4php to add color codes to each log level?

(*Rem : It's not duplicate, My question is about **log4php** not for log4j2*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [log4j 2 adding multiple colors to console appender](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979699/log4j-2-adding-multiple-colors-to-console-appender)

Comment: It's not duplicate. It's a question about log4php not for log4j2.