# Colored Log output, not parsing '%highlight{...}{..}' in log4j.properties

Tags: java, gradle, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I am trying to configure my log output using Log4j and a `log4j.properties` file, but I am having trouble setting up colored output based on log level.

It appears that the logging utilities simply do not parse the `%highlight ...` conversion command.

I can tell that I am on the right track with the configuration, as the other parts of the pattern are working correctly.

I am basing my current code off of this S/O answer: [log4j 2 adding multiple colors to console appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979699/log4j-2-adding-multiple-colors-to-console-appender)

I am assuming it is something simple that I am not seeing, as I am rather new to this. Unfortunately the documentation is hard to piece together, or is meant for xml based configurations.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Some resources I have been looking through already:

- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html
- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
- http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Here are the relevant files/code:

#### log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, STDOUT
log4j.logger.deng=INFO
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%highlight{%d %-5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}
```

#### Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.+'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

#### Test to test logging:

```
@Test
public void testLogger(){
    LOGGER.info("Info level log");
    LOGGER.debug("Debug level log");
    LOGGER.warn("Warn level log");
    LOGGER.error("Error level log");
    LOGGER.trace("Trace level log");
}
```

### Output:

```
log4j:ERROR Unexpected char [h] at position 2 in conversion patterrn.
%highlight{2017-07-08 13:18:21,243 INFO  [main] (LongLinkedListTest.java:40) - Info level log
}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}%highlight{2017-07-08 13:18:21,246 DEBUG [main] (LongLinkedListTest.java:41) - Debug level log
}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}%highlight{2017-07-08 13:18:21,246 WARN  [main] (LongLinkedListTest.java:42) - Warn level log
}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}%highlight{2017-07-08 13:18:21,246 ERROR [main] (LongLinkedListTest.java:43) - Error level log
}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}%highlight{2017-07-08 13:18:21,246 TRACE [main] (LongLinkedListTest.java:44) - Trace level log
}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}
Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Final results:

For posterity, I ended up with the following:

#### Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    //logging dependencies
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.+'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.+'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2+'

    ...
}
```

Once I updated dependencies, I was able to move to a yaml based configuration, and using the `%highlight` notation worked like a charm!

If anyone wishes to see the final configuration, it can be found here: https://github.com/Epic-Breakfast-Productions/OWAT/blob/master/implementations/java/src/main/resources/log4j2.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you're mixing up Log4j2 with log4j 1.x? The `log4j:ERROR` error is an legacy log4j 1.2 error message.

Please simplify matters by only using Log4j2 dependencies and using a Log4j2 configuration. The configuration file is called log4j2.xml by default.

Please remove the `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.+` dependency and instead use log4j-api-2.x, log4j-core-2.x and log4j-slf4j-impl-2.x.

Useful links:

1. [Which jars](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars)
2. [Console appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender)
3. [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) with colors and highlighting
4. [Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

[Log4j 1.2 became End of Life](http://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_logging_services_project_announces) in summer 2015. Let's upgrade! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured that I was using v1.... I was able to use the new dependencies, but now log4j cannot automatically pickup the `log4j.properties` files. Any insight? It looks like I might have to move to an xml or yml based configuration...

Comment: After much fiddling, trial, and error, I got it figured out using a yaml configuration. Thanks again for the push in the right direction!