# Broken Eclipse console log output using Log4J's %style

Tags: logging, configuration, log4j

I created an appender in my Log4J.xml config file following [this manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) :

```
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%green{%d} %style{%t}{BG_Green,white} %yellow{[%-5p]} %m%n"/>
</Console>
```

My broken console output :

```
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:46,394[m [33m[INFO ][m HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:46,659[m [33m[INFO ][m HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:46,751[m [33m[WARN ][m HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:46,755[m [33m[INFO ][m HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernate_demo]
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:46,755[m [33m[INFO ][m HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:46,755[m [33m[INFO ][m HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:46,756[m [33m[INFO ][m HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
[32m2022-02-07 23:58:47,001[m [33m[INFO ][m HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

- I tried to add this `disableAnsi="true"` to my `<PatternLayout />` , didnt work.
- I tired adding [this eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console), didnt work.

Eclipse version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)
Log4J dependency :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

## EDIT 1 :

### it's working partially

I needed to check a checkbox in Window => Prefrences => Run/debug => Console => "Interpret ASCII Control Characters".

Must have this [Eclipse Plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console) installed .

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkIbR.png)

Using `%style{pattern}{myStyles}` is displaying colors in the console correctly , but `%highligh` is not, no idea where to go from here.
[( see console coloring )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkjZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22030994/18145754) is to add `disableAnsi="false"` to my `PatternLayout` like so :

```
<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" >
   <PatternLayout disableAnsi="false" pattern="[ %blue{%d{dd-MMM-yyyy @ HH:mm}} ] %highlight{[%-5p]} %green{[%t]} - %m%n%throwable"/>
</Console>
```